# Expand specific item in treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

How can I expand an item existing in a `TreeView` using code behind?  For example, when I click in my menu I can expand the specific item in my `TreeView`.

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // expand the 3rd item in my treeview
    }
```

code in XAML :

```
<TreeView Height="525" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,47,0,0" Name="treeView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="168" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="12">
        <TreeViewItem Header="PL3 Line 1" IsExpanded="False">
            <TreeViewItem Selected="TreeViewItem_Selected">
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="/MonitoringSystemOfficeArea;component/Images/Computer.png" Height="22" Width="26"></Image>
                        <Label Content="Live Update" Width="70"></Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Selected="TreeViewItem_Selected_1">
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="/MonitoringSystemOfficeArea;component/Images/Calender.png" Height="24" Width="27"></Image>
                        <Label Content="Archives" Width="70"></Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Selected="TreeViewItem_Selected_100">
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="/MonitoringSystemOfficeArea;component/Images/Aha-Soft-Large-Calendar-Calendar.ico" Height="24" Width="27"></Image>
                        <Label Content="Archives / days" Width="88"></Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="PL7 Line 2" IsExpanded="False">
```

...... and so on

Comment: TreeViewItem has a **IsExpanded** dependency property for that purpose. Was that your question? If not, please rephrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ExpandSubtree` method ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.expandsubtree.aspx)):

> **TreeViewItem.ExpandSubtree Method**
>
> Expands the TreeViewItem control and all its child TreeViewItem
>   elements.

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // expand the 3rd item and all its child in treeview      
    TreeViewItem tvi = treeView1.Items[2] as TreeViewItem;
    if (tvi != null)
    {
        tvi.ExpandSubtree();
    }
}
```

If you want to expand only main item you should use `IsExpanded` property ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.isexpanded.aspx)).

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // expand the 3rd item in treeview      
    TreeViewItem tvi = treeView1.Items[2] as TreeViewItem;
    if (tvi != null)
    {
        tvi.IsExpanded = true;
    }
}
```

If you want to collapse the item set `IsExpanded` to false:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // collapse the 3rd item in treeview      
    TreeViewItem tvi = treeView1.Items[2] as TreeViewItem;
    if (tvi != null)
    {
        tvi.IsExpanded = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that ExpandSubTree() does not only expand the item itself, but all chile items as well (according to doc.). That might, or might not be what the OP wants...

Comment: @kmatyaszek thank you so much its working, and how to collapse a specifique iam ?

Comment: @user2933082 if you want to collapse you should set `IsExpanded` to false: `tvi.IsExpanded = false;`